# LC3 right shift on a double world

Tags: bit-shift, lc3

lets say we had the number 510 (0000 0001 1111 1110) 
this is stored in 2 locations

the lowHalf  0000 0001 & 
the highHalf 1111 1110

if we wanted to perform a right shift how do we account of the carry bit? so the result will be

0000 0011 1111 1100

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend right shifting the first 8 bits to see if there was an overflow, and if there was an overflow, shift the 8 left bits and add one. In my example below I used a binary mask to check the 8th bit of the lower half, using the `AND` opcode, I check to see if the bit was set or not.

.

```
.ORIG x3000

    LD R1, DATA         ; load the lower 8 bits into R1
    LD R3, MASK         ; load the mask into R3
    LEA R5, DATA        ; load the mem location of data into R5
    ADD R5, R5, #1      ; offset by 1 to get the upper 8 bits
    ADD R1, R1, R1      ; bit shift right the data in R1
    AND R4, R1, R3      ; check to see if we have overflowed
    BRz NO_CARRY        ; if bit[8] is set then we have a carry

CARRY
    NOT R3, R3          ; 2's complement
    ADD R3, R3, #1      ;
    ADD R1, R1, R3      ; remove bit[8] from the lower 8 bits
    LDR R3, R5, #0      ; load the value of the 8 upper bits into
            ; R3
    ADD R3, R3, R3      ; bit shift right the upper 8 bits
    ADD R3, R3, #1      ; add the carry bit to the upper bits
    ST R1, DATA         ; store the new value into DATA
    STR R3, R5, #0      ; store the new value for the upper bits
    BRnzp END

NO_CARRY
    LDR R3, R5, #0      ; load the value of the 8 upper bits into
                        ; R3
    ADD R3, R3, R3      ; bit shift right the upper 8 bits
    ST R1, DATA         ; store the new value into DATA
    STR R3, R5, #0      ; store the new value for the upper bits

END
    HALT            ; TRAP x25


; Variables 
DATA    .FILL b11111110
        .FILL b00000001

MASK    .FILL b0000000100000000

.END
```

Comment: Wow, you're right. Guess I'm on something today. Same idea applies but with a shift right. I would recommend bit shifting to the left until you get a right bit shift.

Comment: I see why I did a bit shift left, your desired end result was for a left bit shift so I followed that.